# Capturing system information in AIR apps

Tags: windows, linux, macos, air

could you tell me plz - is it possible (and how if yes) to capture following information in AIR application:

- Operation System
- Laptop model and vendor (if laptop)
- Installed applications with versions

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of AIR, AFAIK only the first part is possible. Version 2 is in [beta](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/) and should let you get much more info from the underlying system.

- Operation System:

It's possible to detect the operation system using flex 3, you need to use Actionscript flash.system.Capabilities (see [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/system/Capabilities.html) for the flex reference).

- Laptop model and vendor
- Installed applications and versions

I don't think that is possible using just AIR.

A way around this is to call a third-party app *first* that does the work for you (and which is run first and then calls your AIR app). The app will need to write the necessary information to an XML file / sqlite db somewhere where your AIR app can read and process it.